# bootstrap 5. модальное окно закрывается не полностью

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

```js
$("#open_modal").click(function(e) {
  $('#selectMyCats').show();
});

$("#saveSelectCats").click(function(e) {
  $('#selectMyCats').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="selectMyCats" aria-labelledby="selectMyCatsLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm">

                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Тестирование</h5>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="formAuth" action="javascript:;"></form>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm w-100 mt-2 btn-danger" id="saveSelectCats">Закрыть</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        
<div id="open_modal" data-bs-target="#selectMyCats" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary" >Открыть modal</div>
```

Как видно после закрытия остается затемнение...

Почем так происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Оказываете решение в том что нужно использовать

```
$('#selectMyCats').modal('hide');
```

Вместо

```
$('#selectMyCats').hide();
```